# Iterate through two dataframes and filter based on conditions in columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have two DataFrames like that below:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'wag': [111, 111, 222], 
    'date': ['2019-08-30', '2019-09-20', '2019-08-10']
})
```

and

```
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'wag': [111, 111, 111, 222, 222, 333, 333, 333], 
    'msr_date': ['2019-08-30', '2019-08-30', '2019-08-30', 
                 '2019-08-30', '2019-08-30', '2019-08-30', 
                 '2019-08-30', '2019-08-30'], 
    'measurements': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
})
```

`df_1` and `df_2` are below:

| wag | date |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | 2019-08-30 |
| 111 | 2019-09-20 |
| 222 | 2019-08-10 |

| wag | msr_date | measurements |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 2019-03-29 | 1 |
| 111 | 2019-03-19 | 2 |
| 111 | 2019-03-10 | 3 |
| 222 | 2019-09-30 | 4 |
| 222 | 2019-09-20 | 5 |
| 333 | 2019-08-30 | 6 |
| 333 | 2019-08-30 | 7 |
| 333 | 2019-09-20 | 8 |

So, I have two DataFrames `df_1` and `df_2` and I want to iterate through them at the same time and filter `df_2`. I need to iterate based on `wag` in both tables.

If `wag` in `df_1` is in `df_2` then I have to compare `date` and `mrs_date` and

- if `mrs_date <= date` then I append all rows of that `wag`
- else I check if I have one more condition for that row in `df_1` for that `wag` and again repeat the comparison of dates.
- When conditions / rows are finished for that wags we go to the next value of `wag`.

For example, here I first check the first row of `df_1` and if `mrs_date <= date` in `df_2` then I append all rows to `df_new`.  If not then I go to the next `date` for that `wag`. If we have one if not then check another `wag`. So finally, for this example I will get `df_new` as below:

| wag | msr_date | measurements |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 2019-03-29 | 1 |
| 111 | 2019-03-19 | 2 |
| 111 | 2019-03-10 | 3 |

In reality, there are so many values in `df_1` and in `df_2` so `for_loop` should be quite complicated and I couldn't find the way how to do it. If it is not clear how I described the task please ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merge your 2 dataframes on `wag` column then keep only rows that match your condition `msr_date <= date`. Finally, drop the column `date` from `df_1` and remove duplicates rows.

```
>>> df_2.merge(df_1, on='wag', how='left') \
        .query('msr_date <= date') \
        .drop(columns='date').drop_duplicates()

   wag    msr_date  measurements
0  111  2019-03-29             1
2  111  2019-03-19             2
4  111  2019-03-10             3
```

Comment: @sammywemmy. I failed to get it to work

Answer (score 0):

Using a for loop:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(data=None, columns=df_2.columns)

for idx, row in df_1.iterrows():
  for idx2, row2 in df_2.iterrows():
    if row['wag'] == row2['wag'] and row2['msr_date'] <= row['date']:
      new_df = new_df.append(row2).drop_duplicates()
```

Comment: no point using a for loop for this scenario, as it is going to be slow; you lose the speed of Pandas this way